# /usr/bin/dpkg: 1: /usr/bin/dpkg: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

```
root@tet0-Lenovo-G500s:~# sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
 debianutils git-man krb5-locales less libbsd0 libcurl3-gnutls libedit2 liberror-perl
 libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libnghttp2-14 libpsl5
 librtmp1 libssl1.0.0 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxmuu1
 multiarch-support openssh-client publicsuffix xauth
Suggested packages:
 gettext-base git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb
 git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn krb5-doc krb5-user keychain libpam-ssh monkeysphere ssh-askpass
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 debianutils git git-man krb5-locales less libbsd0 libcurl3-gnutls libedit2 liberror-perl
 libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libnghttp2-14 libpsl5
 librtmp1 libssl1.0.0 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxmuu1
 multiarch-support openssh-client publicsuffix xauth
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,915 kB of archives.
After this operation, 55.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
/usr/bin/dpkg: 1: /usr/bin/dpkg: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: `dpkg -l | egrep -v  '^ii|rc'` please, add the output to your question.

Comment: now it's showing, bash: /usr/bin/dpkg: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error @nobody

Comment: Did you replace `/usr/bin/dpkg` with a shell script or something? What is the output of `file /usr/bin/dpkg`? What commands did you run involving `dpkg` before this?

Comment: Oh, `uname -a` please I need ypur arch.

Comment: That error can happen if `/usr/bin/dpkg` is the wrong binary architecture for your system (such as ARM on x86, or possibly x86_64 on i386)

Comment: Linux tet0-Lenovo-G500s 4.18.0-21-generic #22~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 15:07:33 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux   @nobody

Comment: if that is, then how to fix it? @steeldriver

Comment: Let's confirm first - please add the output of `file /usr/bin/dpkg`

Comment: that contains the binary file as output @steeldriver

Comment: is that the solution to remove the dpkg file and reinstall it again? @muru

Answer (score 1):

Okay 32-bit.

```
mkdir $HOME/dpkg
```

enter this directory

```
cd $HOME/dpkg
```

then download dpkg with wget.

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.19.0.5ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

uncompress the deb package.

```
ar x dpkg_1.19.0.5ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

then we extract the datas.

```
tar xf data.tar.xz
```

then substitute the wrong dpkg.

```
sudo cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/dpkg
```

then try

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

when dpkg is working again.

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

If you get an output,

[remove foreign-architectures](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295241/dpkg-error-cannot-remove-architecture-i386-currently-in-use-by-the-database)

but you have to adapt it to your situation. 
you have to change the part i386 to the one you get from output.
I hope the last part is understandable.

If you are unsure show the output from last command.